# 419 (Unknown Status) Error for POST request using AXIOS and Laravel

Tags: php, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.5

Sorry to bother all of you. I have searched many times. I tried the probable solution too. I have set the csrf_token using meta tag

```
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

My POST request is like the below

```
tryAuth () {

  if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {

    let _this = this

    axios.post('/trylogin',_this.loginInfo, {
      headers: {
        //'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
      },
      //withCredentials: true
    }).then(function(response){

      console.log(response.data)

    })
    .catch(function(error){

    })

  }
```

I have tried both using with and without the headers.
Sometimes the response is okay but sometimes it shows 419 error response.

I am using Laravel 5.5 and AXIOS latest version.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have found some solution and tried but didn't work for me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey! How define the _axios_ in the _bootstrap.js_ ? 
In my code looks like this:
`window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`

and works fine.

Comment: window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    
}
this iis mine bro.but not working :'(

Comment: where is your routes defined, could you give more information. 
the web.php and the controller could be helpful

Comment: Customize Route file name Backend.php
Route::post('/trylogin', 'AuthenticationController@postLogin');
Controller:

    public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request)
    {
     return $request->all();
    }

Comment: I think you should use the original names (web.php, api.php...) because I guess the problem is that.

Comment: Well I will try that bro.tnks :) :)

Comment: I hope it helps!

Comment: no luck though but thanks :)